# Create Custom Type W/ REGEX PATTERN in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql, types

I have a special types that has `C` and following 8 integers, such as `C21032011`. I'd like to enforce this composite type - one Capital C and following 8 integers.

How could I achieve this constraint?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a domain with a check constraint.

```
create domain my_number_type as text
   constraint check_valid_number check (value is not null and value ~ '^C[0-9]{8}$');
```

Then use this domain wherever you want to enforce such a restriction:

```
create table some_table
(
  ...,
  some_nr my_number_type,
  ...
);
```

Comment: upvoted your answer as it's more complete than mine

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CHECK constraint with a regex in the column defintion to prevent inserting strings not conforming to your pattern.

For example

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
...,
mycolumn text CONSTRAINT myformat CHECK mycolumn ~ '^C[0-9]{8}$',
...,
)
```